# Check for specific combinations of values in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array containing both lemons and pears. I want to check if there are exactly five pears and two lemons in that array without creating a separate array for the two. How could I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are **not** a free coding service. Please include code you've attempted in your problem so we can adequately help you.

Comment: What are lemons and pears? Are they objects referred to with such local variables? Are they some sort of strings or symbols that are spelled like that? Are they instances of particular classes with some sort of names like that? Or something else?

Comment: `[:pears, :pears, :lemons, :figs, :pears, :figs, :lemons, :figs, :apples, :pears, :pears].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |fruit, counts| counts[fruit] += 1 }.values_at(:pears, :lemons) == [5, 2] #=> true`. This uses a *counting hash*, [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) with a default value of zero.

Comment: You have no ruby array. Can't proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Array** `count` method to get the count of a particular element in an array.

```
fruits = [:pears, :pears, :lemons, :figs, :pears, :figs, :lemons, :figs, :apples, :pears, :pears]

puts fruits.count(:pears) == 5 && fruits.count(:lemons) == 2 # will return true if the pears is 5 and lemons is 2 in fruit array
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slightly improve the performance compared to straightforward subsequent calls to `count`, you might use `Enumerable#each_with_object`:

```
# Thanks Vishal for the input data prepared
fruits = [
  :pears, :pears, :lemons, :figs, :pears, :figs, 
  :lemons, :figs, :apples, :pears, :pears]

fruits.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |f, acc| acc[f] += 1 }
#⇒ {:pears=>5, :lemons=>2, :figs=>3, :apples=>1}      
end
```